# eslint complaining about unused React var

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have a file that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const I18NLanguage = (props) => {
    const {code, i18n} = props;

    const languageMap = {
        'en': i18n.english,
        'es': i18n.spanish,
        'fr': i18n.french,
        'de': i18n.german,
        'pt': i18n.portuguese,
        'zh-Hans': i18n.simplifiedChinese,
        'zh-Hant': i18n.traditionalChinese,
        'ja': i18n.japanese
    }
    return (
        <>
            {languageMap[code]}
        </>
    )
};

I18NLanguage.propTypes = {
    code: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    i18n: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default I18NLanguage;

// const Input = ({ label, text, type, id, value, handleChange }) => (
//     <div className='form-group'>
//       <label htmlFor={label}>{text}</label>
//       <input
//         type={type}
//         className='form-control'
//         id={id}
//         value={value}
//         onChange={handleChange}
//         required
//       />
//     </div>
//   );

// Input.propTypes = {
//     label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
//     text: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
//     type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
//     id: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
//     value: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
//     handleChange: PropTypes.element.isRequired
// };

// export default Input;
```

When I run eslint, it complains with this error message:

1:8  error  'React' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

If I remove the import to react, it complains about missing the import.  If I comment out everything in the code sample except the two imports, and uncomment the Input function and everything below it, it’s happy.

Any suggestions as to what may be wrong?  My .eslintrc looks like this:

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
      "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "node": true
    },
    "plugins": [
      "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "react/display-name": ["error", { "ignoreTranspilerName": false }],
      "react/no-find-dom-node": [0],
      "no-console": [0]
    },
    "extends": [
      "eslint:recommended",
      "plugin:react/recommended"
    ],
    "settings": {
      "react": {
        "version": "16.4"
      }
    },
    "globals": {
    }
  }
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `eslint` doesn't recognize `<>` (Fragment) as JSX, while `babel` does.

Not sure if updating eslint will fix it, but you can try. Otherwise, just use `<Fragment>` or disable the line from being linted: `import React from 'react'; /* eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars */`

Answer (score 0):

Since the introducing of new jsx transform, you don't need to import react in your case.

> Note how our original code did not need to import React to use JSX anymore! (But we would still need to import React in order to use Hooks or other exports that React provides.)

source: https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html

Hope it helps, have a great day